# php - Laravel - filter relation data inside relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to retrieve `Player` with `user` and `calendars` - Player `hasOne` user and Player `hasMany` calendars.
But I need only male users - works fine, then I have to check calendars collision - select only players without calendar collision, query:

```
$freeplayers = Player::whereNotIn('id', $playersev)
                         ->with('user','calendars')
                         ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                            $query->where('gender', 'male');
                         })
                         ->whereHas('calendars', function ($query) use ($event) {
                             $query->whereNotIn('fulldate', $event->fulldate);
                         })
                         ->get();
```

Second `whereHas` is not working because:

- not every player has an event in calendar (so I cannot access to `fulldate` attr)
- player `hasMany` calendars, so it is returned as another collection, I have to run `->whereNotIn(...` in every item of this calendars collection...

So, I need male players with empty calendar (they are available) and players without collision in their existing calendar.

How can I achieve that? I tried to combine `->doesntHave('calendars')->orWhereHas('cale...` but it's not working because if user have calendar, it is returned as another collection...

Thanks

Comment: can you show what fullDate is?

Comment: @NiRR - just ordinary datetime, for example `2017-11-10 16:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for complete API of the builder, use https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html

you need to do a "sub query" in the sense that you want ONE of the following to occur:
either the calendar is empty or the calendar date is not a specific date.

so

```
Player::where(function($query) use ($forbiddenDatesArray) {
    $query->has('calendars', 0)
          ->orWhereHas('calendars', function($query) use ($forbiddenDatesArray){
              $query->whereNotIn('fullDate', $forbiddenDatesArray);
          });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! It works, thank you, just small typo - **calendars** not calendar :)

Answer (score 1):

whereNotIn checks the value to the given array as second argument

Try

```
->whereHas('calendars', function ($query) use ($event) {
    $query->where('fulldate', '!=', $event->fulldate);
})
```

Update: To get player of no calendar entry

```
->whereHas('calendars', function ($query) use ($event) {
    $query->where('fulldate', '!=', $event->fulldate)
          ->orWhere('fulldate', null);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, now that date check works, but players without calendars are not included

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Well I need players without calendar to be included too :)

Comment: Updated answer for players without calendar.

Comment: This will return only players WITH calendar, if player doesn't have calendar, there is no fulldate property, whole calendar object is empty.
NiRR's solution works

Comment: Yeah! added **null**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158514/discussion-between-abid-raza-and-nidecker).